# Large copied folders. Byte sizes same, but file counts different

Tags: macos, mac, finder, filesystem, file-transfer

I have a few very large folders copied that have the exact same byte size as their originals, but different file counts (off by 1-10 items) than what they should have.

No errors were reported during the copying process. I'm guessing and hoping that these are merely some .DS_Store files that didn't copy over?

NOTE: These folders did require admin approval, which, to my knowledge proceeded without fail.

On small project folders using Git repos, a diff would not be difficult. Worst case scenario, I can download, install, and run a third party diff tool, but don't want to if I don't have to.

1. **Can anyone say to some degree of certainty that these nominal
   file count differences are just negligible hidden OS files?**
2. **What are some common reasons these byte counts would be
   identical, but file counts be off? Is this an indexing issue?**

### UPDATE:

I ran a third party diff tool (Kaleidoscope) which found no differences between the original folders and the destination folders. Still a mystery as to why the file counts would still be different.

Comment: Did you enable to view hidden files? http://tourkick.com/2012/mac-os-x-force-finder-to-show-hidden-files/ This may help you find hidden files.

Comment: Try an rsync -n which does not do anything to the target - and give us a link to Kaleidoscope so we can see what it does,

Comment: Also note .DS_Stores do take up space - one I looked at was 25k

Comment: In order of their respective comments: 1. I always leave hidden files viewable. 2. www.kaleidoscopeapp.com 3. Thanks. I knew they take up disk space, but wasn't sure if/how the OS counted it in the folder info panels.